# Upgrade to Shopware 6.5 did not finish

Tags: upgrade, shopware, shopware6

We recently upgrade to Shopware 6.5 but the update did not fully process leaving database entities, such as columns, tables, triggers, and other items, that should have been removed or changed in place.

This is causing the store to throw multiple errors. Is there a way that we can run the upgrade again?

We identified the issue which prevented the upgrade from fully processing and have resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

Using `phpMyAdmin` or some other database management tool, find the table `migration` and sort by the column `update` descending from newest to oldest. Delete all the the entries that have an `update` date being later than your first attempt of updating to version 6.5 of Shopware. Also make sure the `class` column of those values has a value beginning with `Shopware\Core\Migration\`.

After you deleted the entries, go to the command line, e.g by connecting to your web server via SSH. Navigate to the root directory of the Shopware installation. Then run the command:

```
bin/console database:migrate --all
```

In theory, migrations that had already been executed up to that point should be executed without problems. And since you resolved the issues preventing the other migrations from being executed before, they should then be executed as well. In any case, you should create a backup of your database before you attempt this, just to be sure.